# React testing library: want to understand the difference between container and document.body

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between `container`, `document.body` when we try to render a component using react testing library ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it difference, more like relationship.

From the [official documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container) this is the definition of the `container`:

> By default, React Testing Library will create a div and append that div to the document.body and this is where your React component will be rendered. If you provide your own HTMLElement container via this option, it will not be appended to the document.body automatically.

For example: If you are unit testing a tablebody element, it cannot be a child of a div. In this case, you can specify a table as the render container.

```
const table = document.createElement('table')

const { container } = render(<TableBody {...props} />, {
  container: document.body.appendChild(table),
})
```